# Vectors created as Polydata VTK file not displaying correctly in VisIt

Tags: fortran, visualization, vtk

I'm making improvements to a thermal-hydraulics code written in Fortran by having it write its mesh data to VTK files that can be opened in a visualizer.  Previously, data was simply written to a text file that the user had to manipulate by hand.  I write two files: one for scalar data, which includes the vertices of the sructured mesh cells and the scalar data inside them, the second file for vector data.  Because of the solution algorithm, the vectors lie on the faces of the mesh cells, so I define their location using Polydata points.

I tested my modifications for a small, 500 cell mesh and it worked fine, but I've tried to move up to a bigger, 9,000 cell mesh.  The vectors don't display right.  The mesh has 18 cells in the x-direction, 18 cells in the y-direction and 29 cells in the z-direction.  In the picture I attached below, you can see that there are 18 vectors in the y-direction, which is correct, but only 7 vectors in the y-direction.  I reduced the z-direction mesh to 3 levels to reduce the complexity for here.  I need to determine if this is an issue with the visualizer, the VTK file, or my code.

[image]

I checked the VTK file and it looks to me that everything is there.  Actually, the previous attempt I made involved printing data so the z-direction coordinates varied fastest, then x, then y and that produced a staggered set of vectors in the z-direction.  Making it so x varied fastest, then y, then z produced what you see above.  I was surprised to see this made a difference because the actual content of the VTK file doesn't change.  Of course, I have trouble with writing to VTK format because I can't find much information on it online, so I could be missing something obvious.  I'm attaching the VTK file I wrote below to see if there's something I'm overlooking.  It's a very long file, so I got rid of most of the data for this post and just left the two header sections and a few data points.

```
# vtk DataFile Version 1.0
Vector Data
ASCII
DATASET POLYDATA
POINTS     972 double
0.33500000E-02  0.33500000E-02  0.00000000E+00
0.13000000E-01  0.33500000E-02  0.00000000E+00
0.25600000E-01  0.33500000E-02  0.00000000E+00
0.38200000E-01  0.33500000E-02  0.00000000E+00
0.50800000E-01  0.33500000E-02  0.00000000E+00
0.63400000E-01  0.33500000E-02  0.00000000E+00
... up to 972 values
POINT_DATA     972
VECTORS Axial_Liquid_Mass_Flow_Rate float         
0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.9075E-01
0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.1636E+00
0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.1636E+00
0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.1636E+00
0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.1636E+00
0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.1636E+00
... up to 972 values
```

**In reference to Chris' comment:**

First, the code actually uses two meshes in keeping with the staggered mesh approach: 1) a scalar mesh in which the continuity and energy equations are solved in (pressure, density, enthalpy, and void fraction are defined at the centers of the scalar mesh cells), 2) a momentum cell mesh in which the momentum equations are solved in (velocity is defined at the centers of the momentum mesh cells).  The scalar mesh is defined by the user and the momentum mesh is built on top of it so that the centers of the momentum cells lie on the faces of the scalar cells.

I thought such a mesh would best be captured using the rectilinear format of VTK, but I couldn't figure out how to capture a non-square or rectangular geometry, such as the one shown here:

[image]

So instead, I used an unstructured grid because all the cell vertice information was easily obtainable (this was also easier to print out from the code because I didn't have to make considerations for the connectivity of the cells).  The momentum cells will actually overlap each other because they are setup so that the centers are on the scalar cell faces.  Therefore, only the centers of the cells are important, which is why I used points instead of a mesh to define the velocity vectors.  See the previous figure if I add in a few momentum mesh cells, shown by the red dashed lines:

[image]

I modified the code so that each scalar cell now has six arrays associated with it:
1) x_location(i,j) - the x location, in meters, of the center of the scalar mesh cell
2) y_location(i,j) - the y location of the center of the scalar mesh cell
3) z_location(i,j) - the z location of the center of the scalar mesh cell
4) x_size(i,j) - the size of the scalar cell in the x direction
5) y_size(i,j) - the size of the scalar cell in the y direction
6) z_size(i,j) - the size of the scalar cell in the z direction

The i index represents a column of cells (a channel) stacked in the z direction.  The j index represents a layer of cells, spanning the x,y directions.

A cell can be uniquely identified by the i and j indices.  All scalar cell data is also given with respect to these indices (i.e. density(i,j), enthalpy(i,j), pressure(i,j), etc.).

Comment: Whilst not an answer to your question I don't think a POLYDATA dataset is the most appropriate choice here. Your data seems to be defined on a regular grid, so it would be easier to use a rectilinear or structured mesh. Also, you say your vectors are defined on the faces of the mesh cells, so you should be using CELL_DATA, rather than POINT_DATA. Finally, the example VTK file you provide is not valid (I presume because of the values of 972).

Comment: The mesh is actually defined in the scalar data VTK file.  It is done so with an unstructured grid.  I tried rectilinear at first, but my geometry isn't always a square or rectangle, and I couldn't figure out how to make rectilinear work for those different geometries.  I did start with using cell data but the vectors were all coming from the same point.  A single cell will have 6 vectors associated with it, one for each face of the cell, but cells are connected, so vectors shouldn't be double counted.  It just seemed easier to lay out all the points in the mesh instead.

Comment: A structured grid can have any geometry you like, but it assumes that neighbouring cells are connected, which unstructured grids do not. I think this will be your best bet. Can you include in your question how your coordinates are defined and also how the scalars and vectors are defined (in Fortran)? Out of curiosity, how do you plot your vectors in VisIt if there is no mesh in the vectors file?